# Delete all data of multiple tables in db containing parent-child relationship without passing parameters [Spring boot]

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, sql-delete

I am wondering is there a way that I could delete all data of multiple tables of parent/child without passing the parameters? Because the rows of the shared Id of these table are many, it's inconvenient to always do it by `void deleteAllByUserId(Long userId)`. If i pass id to the method every time, i'll need to do it a lot of times. But it's obvious that I cannot simply do `void deleteAll()` on the multiple cuz it will have the error due to the parent/child relationship. So I'm wondering is there a way to do it in a method in a hit?

For example, if I have three table, which are Table A, Table B and Table C. They all share the key of User_Id.

1. I did not edit my Repository, cuz deleteAll() is written already.
2. **Service Implementation**

   ```
   @Autowired
   private ARepository aRepository;

   @Autowired
   private BRepository bRepository;

   @Autowired
   private CRepository cRepository;


   public void deleteAllDataThreeTable() {
       aRepository.deleteAll();
       bRepository.deleteAll();
       cRepository.deleteAll();
   }
   ```

I have no idea how to delete id by id through passing parameters, cuz there are many rows, and I don't think passing each id is a good way to go. Any idea is a great help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking to delete all children upon deletion of a user, you should use the `ON DELETE CASCADE` functionality of your database server. [This page](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) gives a good example for doing it in MySQL.